# Why mpmath computes $\sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^n\log(n)=\log\left(\frac1 2 \sqrt{2} \sqrt{\pi}\right)$

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sequences-and-series, closed-form-expressions, sage

Working with precision 500 decimal digits, mpmath in sage computes:

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^n\log(n)=\log\left(\frac1 2 \sqrt{2} \sqrt{\pi}\right).\tag{1}\label{1}$$

We believe the LHS of \eqref{1} diverges, so this isn't true.

> Q1. Are there theoretical reasons for mpmath to compute \eqref{1}?

[online code](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxVjkEOwiAQRfck3IElkLYWEjc23MKdcYG2WpICIwwLby-JmNTdvPf_T8Z5iAmZB29xpQTSYo7jOH158DDMkE21O1MJ8W3OqSyU5KJMi0Iunm_W32bLwokx3ishZZAt3uKTB9FddNeEC4-roAS12TXUQf8G-ZWQa_GH7QYn6rLBfY3A6x89avEB80BGGA==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

**Added** Despite the interesting answers, I am ready bet mpmath
doesn't do any analytic stuff not related to summation, it
works purely numerically and the function is treated as black box,
returning real number.

Comment: This looks like the value of a Cesaro (or Abel) summation method.  If npmath uses such summation methods, they should tell you so in their documentation.

Comment: Is $\sqrt{2\pi}$ in the denominator or numerator?

Comment: It is very frequent that algorithmic summation methods produce a consistent value for divergent series. In Pari/gp, sumalt (designed for convergent alternating series) gives the same result.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan ... The value is $$\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\right) = \frac{\log\pi - \log 2}{2}$$

Comment: This evaluation of a "divergent" series should be due to "analytic continuation" of a certain convergence series. Look at the LerchPhi function show below (Iosif Pinelis). Example: $\zeta(-s)=\sum n^s=-\frac{B_{s+1}}{s+1}$ for $B_k$ the Bernoulli number.

Comment: The sum clearly doesn't converge, as its terms do not go to zero. The sum has very oscillatory behavior, so I have no idea where your suggestion that it arrives at the result purely numerically comes from.

Comment: @Wojowu, I think that the reference to working numerically is just the precision with which the CAS claims that the two sides of [(1)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/422595/why-mpmath-computes-sum-n-2-infty-1n-logn-log-left-frac1-2-sqrt2#mjx-eqn-1) agree, not a claim about how the CAS arrived at its answer.

Comment: With your **Added** sentence, the question becomes looking more like a question about inner workings of software (mpmath) and thus apparently inappropriate for MO. To avoid this (impression?), you may want to consider removing this addition and, moreover, amending your question to something like this: "Are there theoretical reasons for (1)?"

Comment: As Aurel says, this phenomenon has already been observed in PARI/GP, see the book by Belabas and Cohen, "Numerical Algorithms for Number Theory - Using PARI/GP", p. 210 mentions exactly the same series. In this book, the computation relies on an efficient algorithm due to Cohen, Rodriguez-Villegas and Zagier for evaluating alternating series. The function used is called SumAlt (p. 209), the PARI/GP code is freely available here: https://www.math.u-bordeaux.fr/~kbelabas/Numerical_Algorithms/ (there is also the built-in PARI/GP function sumalt).

Comment: @IosifPinelis Assuming we know the algorithm mpmath is using (which should not be too hard to figure out, but the OP should make this precise), it is still a non-trivial math question to show that when applied to this particular series, it recovers the regularised value.

Comment: @joro Do you know exactly the algorithm used by mpmath? Apparently several options are possible for the function nsum, so it would be useful if you could do some testing and tell us which one produces this result.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault : (i) I agree that there may be nontrivial math in recognizing a closed-form constant from its (say decimal) approximations. (Do you know if such math exists?) (ii) But it also may be a matter of just keeping a large library of such constants along with their respective decimal approximations, and then nontrivial math is not needed. Since, as you noted, this same series is present in a known book on numerical approximations, this may well be just a type-(ii) case, without significant math content. So, then this is indeed a question about the mpmath inner workings.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Almost certainly mpmath does not recognize the closed-form expression $\log\sqrt{\pi/2}$, it is human's work to find a reasonable candidate for the number output by the computer. My point is that mpmath relies on non-trivial summation algorithms, and why a given algorithm produces a value suggested by theory remains to be proven mathematically. For details see Cohen--Rodriguez-Villegas-Zagier's article "Convergence Acceleration of Alternating Series" p. 6 (they don't provide a proof). In any case, I find OP's current "Q1" rather unclear, and I hope that the OP will clarify it.

Comment: @IosifPinelis I'm not aware of a type (i) algorithm except recognising rational numbers and more generally $\mathbb{Z}$-linear relations (LLL algorithms). For (ii), in the old times there was the Plouffe inverter. It does not exist anymore but if I understood correctly this is now part of OEIS, and here it indeed [works](http://oeis.org/A256358). After that, there still needs to be explained why some summation algorithms also work with divergent series.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault, there's a [recent review of resources](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.16720) for (ii) on arxiv.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault : Thank you for this information. Of course, designing efficient computational methods involves nontrivial mathematics, but the problem here was, rather, how to find the sum of a series in closed form or, perhaps, to find out how a particular kind of software does that.

Comment: @PeterTaylor : Thank you for the reference.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Actually it would be great if the OP could clarify what was the problem exactly...

Answer (score 9):

A summation method for this...
$$
F(s) = -\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^s} = -(2^{1-s}-1)\zeta(s)
\qquad\text{for $s>0$}
$$
Differentiate:
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\log n}{n^s} = F'(s) 
= 2^{1-s}(\log 2)\zeta(s) - (2^{1-s}-1)\zeta'(s)
\qquad\text{for $s>0$}
$$

Now the term-by-term limit as $s \to 0^+$ would be
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^n\log n
$$
which diverges, but
$$
\lim_{s\to 0^+} \big(2^{1-s}(\log 2)\zeta(s) - (2^{1-s}-1)\zeta'(s)\big)
= 2(\log 2)\zeta(0) -\zeta'(0)
\\
= -\log 2 + \frac{\log(2\pi)}{2} = \frac{\log \pi - \log 2}{2}
$$

Answer (score 7):

As shown in my previous answer, the value of the sum that you see is
$$\lim_{t\uparrow1}\sum_{n=2}^\infty (-t)^n \ln n. $$

Here is a "manual" way to show this. Writing
\begin{equation}
    \ln n=\int_0^\infty dz\,\frac{e^{-z}-e^{-nz}}z,
\end{equation}
for $t\uparrow1$ we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{n=2}^\infty (-t)^n \ln n \\ 
    &=\sum_{n=2}^\infty (-t)^n \int_0^\infty dz\,\frac{e^{-z}-e^{-nz}}z \\ 
    &=\int_0^\infty \frac{dz}z\sum_{n=2}^\infty (-t)^n (e^{-z}-e^{-nz}) \\ 
    &=\frac{t^2}{1+t}\int_0^\infty \frac{dz}z\,e^{-z}\frac{1-e^{-z}}{1+t e^{-z}} \\ 
    &\to\frac12\int_0^\infty \frac{dz}z\,e^{-z}\frac{1-e^{-z}}{1+e^{-z}} \\ 
    &=-\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\ln x}\,\frac{1-x}{1+x} 
    = \frac12\,\ln\frac\pi2, 
\end{aligned}   
\end{equation}
by (say) Formula 4.267.1 on p. 545 in I.S. Gradshteyn and I.M. Ryzhik, Table of Integrals, Series, and Products, Seventh Edition, 2007.

Answer (score 2):

The value of the sum that you see is

$$\lim_{s\downarrow-1}\sum_{n=2}^\infty s^n \ln n. $$

Here is the work in Mathematica:

[image: In[1]:=Sum[s^n Log[n], {n, 2, Infinity}, Assumptions->-1<s<1] Out[1]=-s^2Derivative[0,1,0][LerchPhi][s,0,2] In[2]:=Limit[%,s->-1,Direction->"FromAbove"] Out[2]=-Derivative[0,1,0][LerchPhi][-1,0,2] In[3]:=FullSimplify[-Derivative[0,1,0][LerchPhi][-1,0,2]] Out[3]=(1/2)Log[Pi/2]]

**Added by David Roberts (please see the corresponding comment of mine below):** And here is the raw text for copy/paste, with output:

```
In[1]:=Sum[s^n Log[n], {n, 2, Infinity}, Assumptions->-1<s<1]

Out[1]=-s^2Derivative[0,1,0][LerchPhi][s,0,2]

In[2]:=Limit[%,s->-1,Direction->"FromAbove"]

Out[2]=-Derivative[0,1,0][LerchPhi][-1,0,2]

In[3]:=FullSimplify[-Derivative[0,1,0][LerchPhi][-1,0,2]]
Out[3]=(1/2)Log[Pi/2]
```

Comment: I edited in a text equivalent of the Mathematica code.  It's a bit less pretty, but hopefully more useful for anyone searching or C&Ping.  Please feel free to rollback if the edit was unwelcome.  But isn't this a comment, rather than an answer?

Comment: @LSpice : I think readability is more important here, so I did roll it back. I do not see why this may be not an answer. Do you care to explain your comment? In the beginning, I have now added a detail.

Comment: It's funny—I find text more readable than an image!  But of course it's your answer, and I apologise for an unwelcome edit. \\ Your detail in the beginning seems more like an answer, but the original Mathematica code—for someone like me only familiar with Mathematica code to get answers, not to extract the mathematical details—just to be showing that Mathematica produces the same answer; I was not able to extract from it the explanation that you have now added in.

Comment: @LSpice : I would agree that such text is more readable by a computer, but hardly by a human. Also, I have now given (in another answer) a possible way for Mathematica's reasoning.

Comment: Why not both...? pixels are cheap

Comment: @DavidRoberts : I think the shorter the answer is the better, provided that it contains all the necessary information, maybe with just a bit of redundancy for the ease of reading. There is also a concern about the esthetics. This raw text does not look pretty to a human eye. I think almost the entire point of the Mathematica interface was to make the code easily readable by humans. With all that said, as a compromise, I have left your edit, but indicated that it was **your** edit.

Comment: @IosifPinelis that's fair. It was a little cheeky of me, but having the raw text there is useful in case people want to play with the example, and not have to type it out afresh based on a picture of the preformatted version (it wasn't clear to me how one would type some of that stuff!). Also, one can paste this into [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=FullSimplify%5B-Derivative%5B0%2C1%2C0%5D%5BLerchPhi%5D%5B-1%2C0%2C2%5D%5D), if no Mathematica is to hand.